# Good definition of function for integration

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have the following problem:

I define a function:

```
f[t_]:=(1-Exp[-t])/(1+Exp[-t])
```

and integrate it by:

```
g[t_]:=Integrate[f[t],t]
```

then when I try to plot it using:

```
Plot[g[t],{t,0,10}]
```

I get a list of errors of the kind `Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in 1.0000204285714285`.

I don't understand where the problem is, but I expect it to be in the way I defined `g[t]`, even if when I call it I get a well defined expression, namely `-t+2Log[1+e^t]` (also, when plotting this expression directly I don't get any problems). So, how can I solve this problem?

I tried by redefining the function as:

```
g[t_]:=Integrate[f[x],{x,0,t}]
```

but this way it takes a lot of time to plot (if it even does, after about 10 seconds I interrupted it, it is too slow anyway).

Comment: g[t_] = Integrate[f[t], t] fixes it. Think really carefully how evaluation works tiny step by tiny step in your original and I think you might be able to understand why there is an error message. Thinking why this change fixes it is a little harder to understand.

Comment: @Bill Thanks, this is helpful. Would you consider writing an answer explaining why changing `:=` with `=` fixes the problem? I think I have understood the difference between the two, but in this case I don't understand why I should use the first instead of the second...

Comment: Suppose your Plot wants to find the point {x,y} for x=1. So it calls g[1]. Now g[1] defined with := tries to evaluate Integrate[f[t],t] with t replaced everywhere in that by 1. To do that it asks what is Integrate[f[1],1]. At this point I think you are stuck, you are no longer trying to integrate with respect to some variable, but with respect to a constant 1. As Alexey pointed out, = evaluates the right hand side at the moment g is defined and so g is no longer an integral, but an expression. Actually I had hoped you would put in the time to figure this out on your own and benefited more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As correctly stated in the comments, changing `:=` (`SetDelayed`) to `=` (`Set`) in the definition for `g` fixes the problem. The difference between these two definitions is that with `Set` the right hand side of the definition is evaluated at definition time and the closed form of the integral is assigned as a value of function `g`:

```
f[t_] := (1 - Exp[-t])/(1 + Exp[-t])
g[t_] = Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, t}];
Definition[g]

(* => g[t_]=ConditionalExpression[-t-Log[4]+2 Log[1+E^t],E^t>=-1] *)
```

With `SetDelayed` the right hand side (`Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, t}]`) is evaluated at each call of function `g` which results in very slow evaluation.